# In PySpark DataFrames, why is __setitem__ not fully implemented?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In PySpark we can't use the traditional pandas or R-style notation to make new columns based on old ones in a DataFrame. For example, say I try to concatenate two columns:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df['newcol'] = F.concat(df['col_1'], df['col_2'])
```

Result:

```py
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment
```

Instead, the implemented method to do this is

```py
df = df.withColumn('newcol', F.concat(df['col_1'], df['col_2']))
```

Is there a reason PySpark does not implement the traditional DataFrame notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find multiple reasons to implement this way as well as some counterexamples (SparkR API) but it will argue that fundamental reason is implementation purity.

Unlike R or Pandas data frames Spark `DataFrame` is an immutable data structure. Every change of schema creates a completely new `DataFrame` so any operation which would suggest otherwise would be simply misleading.

Theoretically one could get away with implementing `__setitem__` by replacing a reference to JVM `DataFrame` but if you consider that the identity of a `DataFrame` is pretty much definite by `_jdf` this would be quite unpythonic.

Comment: I think I understand. Put another way, traditional dataframes are mutable objects (lists of vectors) whereas Spark DataFrames are immutable because Spark is designed within a functional programming model. `__setitem__` is a mutation and not applicable to an immutable object.

Comment: Yes, exactly... You could implement it yourself and monkey patch but it would smell fishy.